# java regex to fetch uuid after string

Tags: java, regex

I try to fetch the uuid in the following string:

```
146916ad3ed2935cc82ebed705dc27213f907808 add partner request id = e4614f35-1f3c-4316-85c1-016bfffcc928
```

what am i missing as my matcher cannot fetch it

```
@Test
public void requestIdRegex()
{
    String gitCommit = "146916ad3ed2935cc82ebed705dc27213f907808 add partner request id = e4614f35-1f3c-4316-85c1-016bfffcc928";
    String requestId = null;

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+) add partner request id = (\\s+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(gitCommit);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        requestId =  matcher.group(2);
    }
    assertThat(requestId, equalTo("e4614f35-1f3c-4316-85c1-016bfffcc928"));
}
```

how can

Comment: Replace `\\s+` with `\\S+` (and perhaps, `\\d+` with `\\w+`) - see https://regex101.com/r/oqzPYS/1. Well, if you are after just 1 value, why specify 2 capturing groups in the pattern?

Comment: And one more thing, why not `split` with `" add partner request id = "`?

Comment: Or if every variable part of the string is fixed-width, just use `String.substring`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matching pattern for the id is `(\\s+)`. However `\s` matches **whitespace characters**, not **digits** and **minus-signs**.

Try to use a pattern like `([\\w-]+)` which matches all **word-characters** (that are character from *a-z, A-Z, 0-9* and the underscore *_*). Additionally the `-` matches the **minus signs** in the id.

Also your first capturing group only matches **digits**, but it also contains characters *a-z*, you can also change it to `(\\w+)` to solve the problem.

Here is the adjusted code:

```
@Test
public void requestIdRegex()
{
    String gitCommit = "146916ad3ed2935cc82ebed705dc27213f907808 add partner request id = e4614f35-1f3c-4316-85c1-016bfffcc928";
    String requestId = null;

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+) add partner request id = ([\\w-]+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(gitCommit);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        requestId =  matcher.group(2);
    }
    assertThat(requestId, equalTo("e4614f35-1f3c-4316-85c1-016bfffcc928"));
}
```

You can try your regex patterns at **regex101.com**, it also contains explanations of the pattern. Here is a link to your example: [regex101.com/r/7kz5eB/1](https://regex101.com/r/7kz5eB/1)

Answer (score 0):

You may change to :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+) add partner request id = ([-\\w]+)");
```

- `\\w` : any word character

---

As suggest in comment, use `split` would use less lines :

```
String gitCommit = "1469......808 add partner request id = e4614f35-1f3c-4......fcc928";
String requestId = gitCommit.split(" add partner request id = ")[1];
```

Comment: Are you sure that you mean `\\W` in the code? That matches **non**-word characters. In your explanation you also talk of `\w` instead of `\W`.

Comment: @zabuza misType yes

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the regular expression you're using. Try this instead:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d|\\w)+ add partner request id = (((((\\d|\\w))+\\-))+(\\d|\\w)+)");

Matcher matcher = p.matcher(gitCommit);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        requestId =  matcher.group(2);
    }
System.out.println("RequestId = " + requestId);
```

The result is:

```
RequestId = e4614f35-1f3c-4316-85c1-016bfffcc928
```

Comment: Would be helpful for OP if you also explane your changes, I think.

Comment: You could make the pattern a bit clearer by using sets instead of groups using `|`. For example you could exchange `(\\d|\\w)` with `[\\d\\w]`, just in case you did not know, that also minimizes the amount of capturing groups :)

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I will edit my answer :)

Comment: Just use `\w`, it contains `\d`. This also makes `(\d|\w)` prone to create catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: @Aaron I prefer to mark clearly if i am using digits or words, i don't know if that is a bad practice.

Comment: Using `[\w\d]` is alright if you want to be more explicit, just avoid `(\w|\d)`. On the other hand, it shouldn't lead to you think that `\w` only matches alphabetic letters. While I often use it, I wonder if the specification of `\w` was a good idea : how many people ignore/forget it also matches underscores? In this case you could also use `[\da-f]` which is more specific.